# Why can't I pushback a new element to a list

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I met a problem when I try to pushback a new element to a list.

This problem is to write the function implementation of PushBack() according its calling in the main body. So my question is just about the function `PushBack()`.

```
#include <iostream>

 class Node{
 public:
    static Node* MakeNode() { return new Node(100); }
    Node* prev;
    Node* next;
    int value;
 private:
    Node(int num) : value(num), prev(NULL), next(NULL) {}
};

void PushBack(Node* simple, Node* newNode){
    if (simple == NULL){
        //still a empty list
        simple = newNode;
       }
    else{
    //need to loop to the end of list because there is no "tail" in the class
    Node* itr = simple;
    while (itr->next != NULL){
        itr = itr->next;
    }
    newNode->prev = itr;
    itr->next = newNode;
}
return;
}

int main()
{
    Node* simple = NULL;
    PushBack(simple, Node::MakeNode());
    std::cout << (simple == NULL);
    PushBack(simple, Node::MakeNode());
    PushBack(simple, Node::MakeNode());
    PushBack(simple, Node::MakeNode());
    while (simple != NULL){
       std::cout << simple->value << std::endl;
       simple = simple->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have two questions about the argument type of function `PushBack()`:

1. the return type of `MakeNode()` is `static Node*` , but why we need to set the second argument type in `PushBack()` as `Node*`? why not `static Node *`?
2. At beginning, I tried `void PushBack(Node* simple, Node* newNode)` but when the program finish and exit out from `PushBack()`, `simple`becomes `NULL` again.
   So the new elements cannot be added to the list.  I must use `void PushBack(Node*& simple, Node* newNode)`.

Why do I need to add a `&` symbol here? I think if I pass the pointer value into the function, the pointer simple can be changed directly. But it seems this is not the case.

What is the difference between my problem and this segment:?

```
void changeVal(int* data){
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        *(data + i) = 99;
  }
void main()
{
     int *data;
     data = new int[10];
     changeVal(data);
     for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
         std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
 }
```

I passed the pointer `data` into `changeVal()`, and the content can be changed inside the function. I don't quite understand the difference between the two.

I failed to find some useful explanation online so I am asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, the return type of `MakeNode()` is `Node*`.  You can declare a class method as `static` so that you can call the method without needing an instance of the class beforehand, you call the method on the class type itself.  The `static` in this case is not part of the return value, it is part of the class method itself.  As for `PushBack()`, there is no such thing as a `static` function parameter.  The function is acting on a specific instance of the `Node` class, so it is just a regular pointer.
2. When you declare the `simple` parameter as `Node*`, you are passing your `Node*` variable **by value**.  The parameter receives a local copy of the **current value** of the `Node*` variable.  Anything the function does to read or alter the parameter value is done using that *copy*, not the *original* variable.  This is why your `simple` variable in `main()` was not changing when `PushBack()` exited.

   On the other hand, when you declare the `simple` parameter as `Node*&`, you are passing your `Node*` variable **by reference**.  The parameter receives the **memory address** of the original `Node*` variable.  Anything the function does to read or alter the value of the parameter is done using the *original* variable directly, not a *copy*. This is why your `simple` variable in `main()` was changing when `PushBack()` exited.

A **reference** is essentially a compiler-managed pointer.  It is not allowed to ever be set to NULL, and it is auto-dereferenced whenever you read/write a value from/to it.  So, if you think of a reference as an implicit pointer, `PushBack(Node*&)` is functionality equivalent to `PushBack(Node**)` (with extra compiler validation), similar to the following:

```
void PushBack(Node** simple, Node* newNode){
    if (*simple == NULL){
        //still a empty list
        *simple = newNode;
    }
    else{
        //need to loop to the end of list because there is no "tail" in the class
        Node* itr = *simple;
        while (itr->next != NULL){
            itr = itr->next;
        }
        newNode->prev = itr;
        itr->next = newNode;
    }
    return;
}
```

```
PushBack(&simple, ...);
```

Comment: 1. You can totally have static function parameters (in VC++), and 2. That's pretty confusing. The function may receive a _copy_, but that copy is still the exact memory address of the Node object that was passed in, so you can still modify the data at the memory address, but not where Node* is pointing to.

Comment: Where does VC++ define static function parameters? `static` is not a valid parameter modifier.

Comment: When you pass a pointer variable *by value*, you are passing its value, ie the memory address of the object that is being pointed at.  It is NOT passing the memory address of the pointer variable itself. You get that when you pass the pointer *by reference* instead.

Comment: Hi Remy, Thanks a lot for your detailed analysis and I am really appreciated. But I am still not clear about your second point: I know `simple` is a pointer. the `PushBack()` received should be its value, i.e. the Node address `simple` pointed at? What is the difference between my problem with this: `int *data;
 data = new int[10];
 changeVal(data);`
?

Comment: `changeVal()` is not altering the value of the `data` parameter itself, like `PushBack()` needs to for its `simple` parameter.  `changeVal()` is simply filling the array that `data` is pointing at (using pointer arithmetic to access the array elements).

Answer (score 1):

You need pass a pointer reference and not just a pointer  so that
the address pointed by simple can be changed inside the PushBack function.

Here is a definition from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1sf8shae.aspx).

> References to pointers can be declared in much the same way as
>   references to objects. Declaring a reference to a pointer yields a
>   modifiable value that is used like a normal pointer.

Let me create a simple illustration:

Address | Value

```
[0001]->
[0002]->
[0003]->
[0004]->
......
[nnnn]->
```

When you start your program you have variable simple pointing to NULL:

```
[0001]->NULL 
[0002]
[0003]
[0004]
......
[nnnn]
```

When you call PushBack the firstime you are just passing the value pointed
by simple variable which is just NULL.

```
[0001]->NULL
```

When you change its value inside your PushBack function it, you are just
changing the local copy of that function and not the actual pointer simple variable.
After your call to PushBack is completed, your simple variable is still pointing
to NULL.

Now when you pass a reference pointer, you are passing the modifiable value of simple variable used as a pointer. When you change the value of the pointer, you are also changing the value pointed by the actual simple variable.
After PushBack is called using a pointer reference, simple variable will
now be pointing to the address of new instance returned by MakeNode.

```
[0001]->newNode 
[0002]
[0003]
[0004]
......
[nnnn]
```

Comment: Hi Christian, Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried to understand it but I still have a bit confusion. I think the memory address has been passed into the function, so I think the operation can effect the original value directly...Why it is a local copy? I added a new segment of code at the original problem. What is the difference between this two? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a nice reference with illustration:
https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/cp4_PointerReference.html