# Why can't I add items into my vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I have the following code in one class:

```
    class A
    {
        std::vector<Parameter*> params;
        std::vector<Parameter*> getParamVector() {return params;}
        void addOneParam(Parameter* param)
        {
            params.push_back(param);
        }
    }
```

In another class, **class B**, I try to add items into the **params** vector by doing this:

```
classA_Ptr->getParamVector().push_back(aParamPtr);
```

But the **params** vector's size still 0, after above call.

I have to add above `addOneParams(Parameter* param)` method to add items into the **params** vector. Why?

Comment: I had a similar Problem several days ago. You can see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30114553/why-cant-i-pushback-a-new-element-to-a-list

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`getParamVector()` returns a *copy* of `params`. So when you `push_back` onto it, you're adding to a temporary `vector` that gets deleted right away. That in no way affects `params`'s size.

If you want to be able to do this via `getParamVector()`, you'll have to return a *reference* to `params` instead:

```
std::vector<Parameter*>& getParamVector() {return params;}
                      ^^^
```

Comment: If I want to return a pointer of the vector, it should be like this: std::vector<Parameter*>* getParamVector() {return &params;} ?

Comment: @peterboston Yes, that syntax would be correct. The difference would be that returning a reference makes it clearer that you are returning an actual object, whereas returning a pointer could mean that the caller would need to check against `nullptr`.

Answer (score 3):

You should return either by reference or pointer as pointed out.

```
std::vector<Parameter*>& getParamVector() { return params; }
```

or

```
std::vector<Parameter*>* getParamVector() { return &params; }
```

But, here is the real question: if you already have a method that can add one parameter, why do you need to call getParamVector().push_back().

Instead, you could just do classA_ptr->addOneParam(p).

EDIT: To me addOneParam() enforces data hiding better than getting a reference/pointer to the internal vector.

If the data structure to store the parameters changes, the caller will need to be modified as well.

With addOneParam(), the caller is insulated.

Comment: He doesn't already have a method that can add one parameter, he had to add it uninterestingly. He wants to get rid of it!